# Generating grub.cfg without Linux installed

Tags: grub2, grub, live-usb

My dual boot machine went haywire yesterday, and seriously corrupted the Linux partition.
Among the corrupted files were:

1. The entire `/boot` directory
2. Quite a few stuff in `/bin`

*"No problem"*, I thought to myself. I haven't been using that Linux partition anymore (it's my gaming PC), so I'll just rebuild the boot directory and leave it at that.

*Problem is:* due to corruption of the bin directory, I can't `chroot` into the system. And since `grub-mkconfig` (or `update-grub`) can't be run from a live USB, I have no way of generating the `grub.cfg` file.

The live USBs I have here (Arch Linux and gparted) both have scripts inside grub.d/ for detecting OS's.
In gparted, `grub-mkconfig` fails to run entirely. While in arch linux it runs but detects nothing.

**Is there a way of generating grub.cfg without a working Linux installation?**

Comment: have you consider the use of the supergrub disk ?

Comment: @kiwy hadn't heard about it. Will look into it.

Comment: Another option is parted magic, which should allow you to destroy your linux partition and resize your windows one. http://partedmagic.com/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with the Arch Linux live USB. The reason why it wasn't finding anything is that `os-prober` wasn't installed.

So it was just a matter of installing it on the live USB itself:

```
pacman -Syy
pacman -S os-prober
grub-mkconfig
```